# How do you add subtle details to a normal map?

Tags: normals, normal-map

Ive intensified this normal map to show what's really going on. The detail is so faint in the normal map its pretty much invisible, its almost like theres another texture overlaying that part of the map. How do you add subtle detail like this to a normal map?

[image]

Comment: Shade smooth your model before (and after) baking the normal map.

Comment: Im asking how you ADD texture like this to the normal map. This is not a smoothing issue.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Are you talking about the _little_ bumps on the surface?

Comment: Yes this is an asset I pulled from elsewhere. Its not mine. I was looking at the normal map for it and noticed it has alot more detail in it. Just not sure how to add that softly. Every time Ive tried to do it, it comes out harsh in the normals and throws off the shading.

Comment: Well, the _strength_ of you normal node is 10 which is way too high (1 is usually the max needed) - is there some reason you need it that high? Are you saying that's what's required to make the "fine details" stick out?

Comment: Yes, i strengthened the node to see exactly how it was affecting the object. Not necessarily required. I just cant see the details very well under my scene lights and 
 the object probably has some other textures for the roughness and specular, I just couldnt find them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add detail from another Normal Map (in this case a Noise Texture) by either combining an existing *Normal Map Image Texture* (like the one you have above) through a *Normal Map Node* OR a black and white "heightmap" texture through a *Bump Node*, and then combining the two using an *Vector Math* node set to "Add" (default), In the image below, I mixed the Noise Texture (heavily) with white to soften the look. You can use the slider to control the influence, however I recommend keeping the mix between .96 and 1 (very high, I know - noise textures are *strong*)

[image: Add]

EDIT - To make the "mixed" normal affect certain areas differently, you can either assign different materials to those faces (islands) and manipulate them that way, or you could use a black and white image texture as a mask (I used a checker texture for the example). You will need to mix the Normal Maps using a MixRGB node instead of a Vector Math (so you have access to the "fac" input), so you will lose *some* precision, but it will be negligible. If you want to cover certain islands, you may want to save an image texture of your UV islands, convert it to black and white (in some photo editing program) and super saturate the contrast (so the light grey/white areas become solid white and the dark grey/black areas become solid black), and then literally "paint over" the islands you want omitted with black. This could get rather complicated if you want multiple variations, though. For that, I suggest simply using different materials.

[image: UVedit]

Comment: How would I add a noise texture to only one part of the UV map? Like If i had an object with multiple parts unwrapped and I wanted to add a different texture to each UV island?

Comment: I added an edit to my answer with some possible ways.

Comment: Sorry Im a little confused, I would assume adding a different material to each part would be the way to do it like you said . Would that mean baking out the procedural materials into a single separate normal map and than blending the two together?

Comment: Its hard to tell without knowing more of your setup, but yes, you could do it that way. You could also add a noise texture (or other texture) to each of your materials the same way as the above  example.